# How to access a particular set element using iterator?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

Need a simple bi-directional dictionary. I understand there might be better solutions but I want to understand where I am wrong with this one. The algorithm is based of three things:

- it needs to be symmetric (work exactly the same regardless of translation direction)
- store every word once
- more or less fast/optimal.

I decided to use set to store words, and two maps that would point to that set like this:

```
map <ptr:word_to_translate_from, ptr:word_to_translate_to>
```

I am using set assuming that no insertion will invalidate previously acquired iterators.

The initialization seems to be going as I expected, but having found an iterator to the word that needs to be translated, I am failing to access dictionary set (words). My thinking goes like this:

- I have two maps that store iterators of type std::setstd::string pointing to the words I need;
- I am finding requested word and assigning respective iterator to fw of type `std::set<std::string>::iterator`;
- I expected to get translation by doing this: `*(forward.at(it))`, where `at(it)` would get me a key to required element of forward, `forward.at(it)` would get me iterator to the translation, and `*` would bring up the word itself. But this line breaks the execution.

Where I am wrong?

```cpp
struct comparator {
    bool operator() (const std::set<std::string>::iterator& lhs, const std::set<std::string>::iterator& rhs) const {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};

class Translator {
public:
    Translator() = default;
    void Add(std::string_view source, std::string_view target) {        

        auto [fw, fw_ok] = words.insert(std::string(source));
        auto [bw, bw_ok] = words.insert(std::string(target));
        forward.insert({fw, bw});   // inserting a pair of std::set<std::string>::iterator
        backward.insert({bw, fw});      
    }
    
    std::string_view TranslateForward(std::string_view source) const {
        
        std::set<std::string>::iterator it = words.find(std::string(source));
        if (it == words.end() || forward.count(it) == 0) return std::string_view{};
        auto& ret = *(forward.at(it));
        return ret;             
    }
    std::string_view TranslateBackward(std::string_view target) const {
        
        std::set<std::string>::iterator it = words.find(std::string(target));
        if (it == words.end() || backward.count(it) == 0) return std::string_view{};
        auto& ret = *(backward.at(it));
        return ret;             
    }

private:
    std::set<std::string> words;
    std::map<std::set<std::string>::iterator, std::set<std::string>::iterator, comparator> forward;
    std::map<std::set<std::string>::iterator, std::set<std::string>::iterator, comparator> backward;
    int index = 0;
};

void TestSimple() {
      Translator translator;
    translator.Add(std::string("fenster"s), std::string("window"s));
    translator.Add(std::string("tisch"s), std::string("table"s));

    assert(translator.TranslateForward("fenster"s) == "window"s);
    assert(translator.TranslateBackward("table"s) == "tisch"s);
    assert(translator.TranslateForward("table"s) == ""s);
}

int main() {
    TestSimple();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your comparator for the maps has undefined behavior.  You can't compare the addresses of distinct objects that aren't part of an array together.

Comment: `auto ret = *(forward.at(it));` Even without compiling, the Visual Studio IDE tells me that `auto` deduces to `std::string`. So the function returns a view to a local variable.

Comment: A common mistake made by new programmers is to write **lots** of buggy code before checking if any of the code is buggy.  There are many mistakes in the code you show here, and the best choice right now may be to first write a simpler program and make sure that program works as intended.

Comment: NathanOliver. yes, I wanted to compare strings, not addresses, my mistake, changed the code in the question.

Comment: `return std::string_view(""s);` you are returning a view to a temporary string object. You get UB.

Comment: 273K, thank you, corrected.

Comment: A note: `string_view` literals are a thing, so a lot of the cases where you use `std::string` literals with an `s` suffix, making it an `sv` suffix would work equally well (and avoid allocating a `std::string`). e.g. `TranslateForward` accepts and returns `string_view`s, so you can change to `assert(translator.TranslateForward("fenster"s) == "window"s);` to `assert(translator.TranslateForward("fenster"sv) == "window"sv);` and avoid creating runtime strings for no reason (`string_view` literal data is stored in program constants, and the object just references the constants).

Comment: `forward.at(it)` throws error when you try to access iterator to `"table"` because it doesn't exist in your map. Note that in this case `it` is not a key in `forward`  but in `backward`

Comment: i think converting `auto ret = ` to `auto& ret =` will solve your bug

Comment: Ahmed AEK, absolutely yes, thank you.

Comment: @AhmedAEK: Or more simply, just condense the two lines to just `return *forward.at(it);`. So many people seem to think they have to store the return value to a variable, then return the variable, but it's simpler and easier to just return the expression itself (and avoids mistakes in this case).

Comment: ShadowRanger, thank you, I cannot change s to sv as this is a task condition. Can I instead use argument like this: source = *(forward.at(it)); and then return source? It compiles and works on my machine.

Comment: Darkolin, thanks, added a condition, now it seems to be working.

Comment: @Xenox: What task condition would allow `std::string` literals but not `std::string_view` literals? And why not just `return *forward.at(it);` directly? `auto& source = *forward.at(it); return source;` and `auto sourceit = forward.at(it); return *sourceit;` both work, but it's pointless when `return *forward.at(it);` does the same thing without unnecessary locals that are created solely to be returned a line later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a couple issues here:

1. `auto ret = *(forward.at(it));` deduces `ret` to be `std::string` (copying the value from the `set`). But you return `std::string_view`, which will be a view of this function-local variable (which no longer exists after returning).
2. You're treating "exists in `set`" as equivalent to "`map` lookup will work", but "exists in `set`" only guarantees lookup will work in *one* of the two `map`s, not both; if it was the `source` of an `Add` call, you can only look it up in `forward`, if it was the `target`, only in `backward`. When the `.at` fails because the mapping is only in the other direction, your program dies due to an unhandled `std::out_of_range`.

Problem #1 is trivially fixed by just *not* copying the `string` to a local. Easiest way to do that is to get rid of the pointless `ret` variable, and just return the result of the lookup directly.

Problem #2 can be fixed in multiple ways, but given you're using `.at`, exception handling is one obvious way to do it.

Fixing both issues (and reducing verbosity by changing explicit typing to `auto` for the iterator, and using `""sv` for the empty `string_view` since you're clearly using literals anyway), and assuming a missing mapping is the same logical meaning whether or not it was in the `set`, your broken functions become:

```
std::string_view TranslateForward(std::string_view source) const {
    auto it = words.find(std::string(source));
    if (it == words.end()) return ""sv;
    try {
        return *forward.at(it);             
    } catch (const std::out_of_range&) {
        return ""sv;
    }
}
std::string_view TranslateBackward(std::string_view target) const {   
    auto it = words.find(std::string(target));
    if (it == words.end()) return ""sv;
    try {
        return *backward.at(it);
    } catch (const std::out_of_range&) {
        return ""sv;
    }
}
```

According to your comments, `sv` literals may be forbidden; returning plain `""`, or if you insist on being explicit, `std::string_view("")`, instead of `""sv`, will work just fine. Returning `std::string_view(""s)`, as you did in some versions of your code, will *not* work, as `""s` is a temporary `std::string` that ceases to exist almost immediately, so the `std::string_view` would be a view of dead data.

With these changes (plus necessary `#include`s), [your code passes all the `assert`s](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMwapK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgkgCcpAAOqAqETgwe3r4BQemZjgJhEdEscQnJtpj2JQxCBEzEBLk%2BfoG19dlNLQRlUbHxiSkKza3t%2BV3j/YMVVaMAlLaoXsTI7Bzm/uHI3lgA1Cb%2BbqIKSq0n2CYaAII7eweYx6csTKnXtw9muwz7XiOJzcSgIX3uj3%2Bz1eIIIWFUm1SYP8NwhvyegJewPGxHCwHBPz%2BAKBpxxeIA%2BgA3PCYADuBO%2BXkyRkOzDYClSTE2h3G6BAIFohHiYgUJysEPuOK8DkOaBYnOITCIxGOAHZxXdDlrDjFUJ5DqhUsLlRAlocIGgGOMeXD%2BaDsbaQGSjNd%2BULFcrzAA2Q60BAKUiygTW3l2zDI2F8p0EXEulFugjGkjew7Ef1my3Wkzq77avOp8PrBiHABUfoUMNLadF/g1eezABFvo2xc37vsmBdDgAVRVWgzKtUa1JeGKC5AgXPa3uGBQDkim14Nw5YKhMLy0ZF17WU1B4dCHO7odAQUPR2PAKk02k8tYbTCBs/Oy/UumHCbAcNm7MWfPatuan%2BhzrkQxwAKwWFQtKBlB5KoAA1iYYHLicy60iQ6AKAAdJg8oGJsp53psSytvcQHAV4oFIRYMTQTqtJwYhyFLoc6HEJhOF4VymAQB%2BX6kYBf78MQtItOgWHhJcBAQD%2BUGBrRjYkbW2oAPQqYcknxI4LJMIcnJ4CqqBUDaUb2qSjrPq6IDukqyZkUBMRcvBonsRJVpaTJ6q0TB9Kqg2Sm/vmU5ai29khWFJl2jGFKvjeM79kqmAAGIkC5J5PtFRhXm%2BChEZgGbBgQQ7BUFEV5iBqAaUVqGsRh2E0Aw6UWZlwCEesxEBSVeZ4MZECEEuNVsRxrimmaxCFsQxbmGY00KJSAnkTGACexVlUB40EEWpbCWlWFKn1BABeRpWCUFfmykqyAIOamZFWeawEHBVDkn2n7et%2BOZrX%2BG1bdNs3zbWXX/n5JWhadGUXtlcV9nOiUWE5aWns1kOxe%2BLSfodQZWtVn2nfWX0UaB/WDXVWENU1pktbx6Nfp1BM9eaxP%2BE2zO1ex2EjUsY0TVNZgzXzc0LUBy2rXj6086WjnIM5Yl7dJhB02LIXnaIBBXTdhWRSAD1PS9hhvWYXofdux0Fptk3HHz/1C3%2BYP1iDEp3KkuKUolk4RU%2B4YOpTF7XGzmE21r7yfOZple6HUW%2B/G1mJh6JCPhZ4eRpHeJWTZyqBnKCq2cQfs7WJgdnsH3thhGEOp9H6fx1rZnJ%2BeFfYAmSZkEG8otDnftSzL7GB%2BERXhPCLEaAJLaA47u77j2mDjEIeB4TxxtA/FsODjGs7zrnY%2BnWvCXKlhR4UynRgyXzVCMOM8SzSsNdU9NtID6g9IC1zgc7yvJD78eSM%2B3iJ9mI4CgrpXwTj/Y%2B01mhjkwFfRWJVOxSV4jDDeWFl4DmSqlMSf8z7Y0vgLSk35mY1Tvg/J%2BZg5qK3KhcDyb8kEoLhgjDB4CmCQP%2BvglmKE%2BYAKAbg8h2o4FUMQTnZBAjEwpREgwjhTD6AsIGqzP63CR4OwePcPuhx3jhEXD%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%2BgdSuDltIDu%2BIkRWBbAXeU3d7TKKbtpB23gQ7kB3GIFCjJwRXnICaPgOxvB0XCFEOINFshMVqDSbi/FRhCUCuJb81VEBKUgGpXNOlDLNDMureyho3LeXM35VYSwLKFVKv3E8yAEa8rurhOENd07Z23oRbSRUqQ%2B2NpsaQO96SODYHfZRUtKa00ZqzTmvN/gsJcHNC4qDNhDjFsHDsCtva8lsoQJgJgWAEhqqsU23grb21pK7bYHtVb/GkECf4ZNWEzDJo0F6VUYEkiqn8GBSQybU2Nv8HGztr6jNss02YDzCqvN9pWAyzIzhJBAA%3D) with no issues, even with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

---

As a side-note: If you opt-in to heterogeneous comparators, you can avoid constructing `std::string`s quite so often (allowing you to benefit from your use of `std::string_view` to avoid constructing `std::string` more reliably). To enable it, just change the declaration of your `set` to:

```
std::set<std::string, std::less<>> words;
```

which explicitly passes a non-type specific comparator that will transparently compare `std::string` and `std::string_view` without needing to convert one to the other. Now you can replace `auto it = words.find(std::string(source));` with just `auto it = words.find(source);`.

Whether or not you opt in to heterogeneous comparisons, you can also avoid the explicit `std::string` creation by changing your `words.insert(std::string(source))` to `words.emplace(source)` (with similar changes for the similar line for `target`); `emplace` knows it's receiving arguments to *construct* the value, not the value itself, so you're not forced to convert it yourself. It won't improve performance much, if at all (due to limitations on heterogeneous comparators that make it construct the `std::string` anyway), though perhaps some future C++ standard might eventually make `.insert` or `.emplace` handle this similar to how `.find` does now (to avoid constructing the object when it already exists now, you'd have to do the `find`-and-conditionally-`emplace` work yourself, which probably isn't worth the hassle).